# XNA C# Multi-threading causes ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, multithreading, xna

I want to utilize multi-threading so I can have more particles in the simulation.

```
public List<droplet> droplets = new List<droplet>();
private void collide(int indexOfA, int indexOfB)
{
    // collision code that only changes the position of droplet A and B
}
```

In the update method;

```
if (droplets.Count > 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < droplets.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i; j < droplets.Count; j++)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => collideParticles(i, j));
            t.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

i is immediately out of range and is usually 1 or 2 when the exception occurs.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

EDIT: For those curious as to what the collide method does, see below.

```
if (droplets[i].collisionRectangle.Intersects(droplets[j].collisionRectangle))
            {
                if (distanceBetween(droplets[i].position, droplets[j].position) < reactDistance * reactDistance)
                {
                    Vector2 sumVector = droplets[i].velocity + droplets[j].velocity;
                    Vector2 resultVector = sumVector / 2;
                    droplets[i].velocity = resultVector;
                    droplets[j].velocity = resultVector;

                    if (droplets[i].position.X > droplets[j].position.X) //x axis
                    {
                        droplets[i].velocity.X += repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].velocity.X -= repelSpeed;

                        droplets[i].position.X -= -repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].position.X += -repelSpeed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        droplets[i].velocity.X -= repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].velocity.X += repelSpeed;

                        droplets[i].position.X += -repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].position.X -= -repelSpeed;
                    }

                    if (droplets[i].position.Y > droplets[j].position.Y) //y axis
                    {
                        droplets[i].velocity.Y += repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].velocity.Y -= repelSpeed;

                        droplets[i].position.Y -= -repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].position.Y += -repelSpeed;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        droplets[i].velocity.Y -= repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].velocity.Y += repelSpeed;

                        droplets[i].position.Y += -repelSpeed;
                        droplets[j].position.Y -= -repelSpeed;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Yes, it's a mess.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. Seems it comes from your `collideParticles` method. Could you show its implementation ?

Comment: Added to bottom of question.

Comment: Do you have same behaviour when avoiding multi-threading ? Did you try to debug it ?

Comment: **With multi-threading:** out of range exception.

 **Without multi-threading AND calling 'collide' method:** works, but low frame-rate. 

**Without multi-threading AND collision code is inside update method:** works, smooth frame-rate.

Comment: It looks like the problem is multi-threading. Maybe because some threads are still running when you update/delete some droplets (later in your code) ? Anyway, you know where it comes from. Next step: find why (and/or an alternative)

Comment: Multi-threading simply changes the position of a droplet's velocity and position. Why would it even cause any errors?

Comment: First, you're trying to collide particles into each other. Your first call is collidePartcles(droplets[0], droplets[0]). Not good. Also, you're manipulating the same droplet multiple times simultaneously.

Comment: Why would that cause an error? All that happens is the same particle's position and velocity gets changed twice simultaneously. How does that cause an error?

Comment: @ShadowByte "All that happens is the same particle's position and velocity gets changed twice simultaneously." I don't think you understand the enormity of the problems this concurrent tinkering is causing. The droplet isn't in a proper state when the subsequent call starts tinkering with it. Each droplet is going to have to collide with another particle in successive order. You're not going to be able to do it all at once.

Comment: I don't understand your point. I'm on Stack Overflow because I want to know how I can get this to work.

Comment: @ShadowByte You can fix it by a) not colliding droplets with themselves and b) only having one collidePartcles() call at a time for a given droplet. For example, you can have collideParticles(0,1) running at the same time as collideParticles(2,3), but collideParticles(0,1) running at the same time as collideParticles(0,anyOtherIndex) or even collideParticles(1,anyOtherIndex) will cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Can I recommend that you use a thread-pool for this kind of thing? Allocating a thread isn't cheap and you're doing in an inner-loop likely while rendering (ouch!).

The real problem I'm seeing here is that there's memory barrier at work here, meaning the values of i & j are for all intents and purposes non-deterministic. Changing collideParticles to a print function:

```
    static void collideParticles(int i, int j)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("i = {0}, j = {1}", i, j);
    }
```

I get the following spew:

```
i = 1, j = 3
i = 2, j = 3
i = 3, j = 3
i = 2, j = 3
i = 2, j = 3
i = 2, j = 3
```

Moving the thread spawn into the collideParticles nets the "expected" result.

```
i = 0, j = 0
i = 0, j = 1
i = 0, j = 2
i = 1, j = 1
i = 1, j = 2
i = 2, j = 2
```

Comment: This is bad. The order of the calls isn't the problem. The concurrency on the same droplet is.

Comment: So is there a solution to my problem? How would you efficiently process collision between hundreds of particles?